# concatenate multiple fields in sqlldr

Tags: bash, shell, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am working on sqlldr(sql loader) in oracle 11g.
I am trying to concatenate 3 fields into a single field. Has anyone done this?

ex: 
TABLE - "CELLINFO" where the fields are (mobile_no,service,longitude).

The data given is (+9198449844,idea,110,25,50) i.e. (mobile_no,service,grad,min,sec).

But while loading data into the table i need to concatenate the last 3 fields (grad,min,sec) into the longitude field of the table.

Here i cant edit manually because i have 1000's of data to be loaded.

I also tried using ||,+ and concat().... but I am not able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ctl may be:

```
load data
append
into table      cellinfo
fields terminated by ","
(
mobile_no,
service,
grad BOUNDFILLER,
min BOUNDFILLER,
sec BOUNDFILLER,
latitude ":grad || :min|| :sec"
)
```

suposing cellinfo(mobile_no, service, latitude).

Some nice info [here on orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Can_one_selectively_load_only_the_records_that_one_needs.3F)

Alternatively, you can modify your input:

```
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2","$3":"$4":"$5}' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `latitude EXPRESSION ":grad || :min || :sec"`?

Comment: My ctls at work use `expression` :), but in the link I posted I've seen examples without expression. I didn't tried without `expression`. Let's say what kattashri says.

Comment: it seems to me that if you don't use `EXPRESSION`, then you must have some field in the input data, that you can reference in the expression.

Comment: sorry guys for the late reply... i havent implemented yet. as soon as i implement it, i will comment my result. thanks for your help in advance.